# Can't figure out why my images will not display on this site

Tags: image, .htaccess, url-routing

On this site:
http://church.allthingswebdesign.com/

None of my images are displaying anymore. They used to, but i'm not sure why they don't anymore. Not sure if it's something i've changed or what.

I'm 100% positive the images exist in the folder images because i've checked the remote copy of the files to make sure i can preview them and i can.

EDIT:

I had one redirection setup to redirect www.allthingswebdesign.com to allthingswebdesign.com. I thought this is what was causing it, but when i deleted that redirect through the cpanel, it still didn't change anything. Does this take some time to go into effect?

Here is the .htaccess file that i found on the server, probably from the redirect i setup in the cpanel. Would this be the cause?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://allthingswebdesign.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://allthingswebdesign.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.allthingswebdesign.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.allthingswebdesign.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ http://allthingswebdesign.com [R,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a duff rewrite rule somewhere in your .htaccess or httpd.conf files. If you try to access an image directly you get redirected to http://allthingswebdesign.com/

---

EDIT: Your problem is definitely your rewrite rules.

Your HTTP_REFERER will be "church.allthingswebdesign.com" so all those conditions will be **true** and the rewrite rule following says "Assuming the above conditions are true, any request for an image should be redirected to http://allthingswebdesign.com"

The simplest solution would be to add more conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://church.allthingswebdesign.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://church.allthingswebdesign.com$      [NC]
```

Comment: i just see that you edited your answer after i started a bounty. I'll try your answer when i get home.

Comment: Adding those 2 lines to the end didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you add them just before the RewriteRule line?

Comment: Oh no i added them at the end. I'll try that.

Answer (score 3):

The image files seem to be there, because you have directory listing turned on on your webserver: http://church.allthingswebdesign.com/images/

However the actual image URLs such as http://church.allthingswebdesign.com/images/church.jpg redirect to http://www.allthingswebdesign.com , so there must be some server-side script/configuration doing that.

Comment: Sorry, web server configuration isn't my area of expertise and neither is really Stackoverflow. Maybe you should try http://serverfault.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Fiddler2 is showing all the images are returning 302 (redirect).  Sounds like Apache has an errant redireect somewhere. This is what I am getting:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://allthingswebdesign.com">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.16 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at church.allthingswebdesign.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

the links to the images are not correct - currently the images are trying to be found at http://church.allthingswebdesign.com/images/church.jpg and this location redirects to allthingswebdesign.com

if you check the links are working correctly then your problem will be fixed